# How exactly works this CodeIgniter controller class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am a Java developer (I often used Spring MVC to develop MVC web app in Java) with a very litle knowledge of PHP and I have to work on a PHP project that use **CodeIgniter 2.1.3**.

So I have some doubts about how controller works in **CodeIgniter**.

1) In Spring MVC I have a controller class with some annoted method, each method handle a specific HTTP Request (the annotation defines the URL handled by the method) and return the name of the view that have to be shown.

Reading the official documentation of **CodeIgniter** it seems me that the logic of this framework is pretty different: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#what-is-a-controller

So it seems to understand that in **CodeIgniter** is a class that handle a single URL of the application having the same name of the class name. Is it correct?

So I have this class:

```
class garanzieValoreFlex extends CI_Controller {

    ..................................................... 
    ..................................................... 
    ..................................................... 

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
    }


    public function reset() {

       $this->session->unset_userdata("datiPreventivo");
       $this->load->view('garanziavalore/garanzie_valore_questionario_bootstrap',array());

   }


   public function index() {

        $this->load->model('Direct');
        $flagDeroga = "true" ;

        $this->session->userdata("flagDeroga");

        $data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
        $this->load->model('GaranzieValoreFlexModel');

        $data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
        $this->load->model('GaranzieValoreFlexModel');

        $this->load->view('garanziavalore/index_bootstrap',$data);
    }

    public function back() {

        $this->load->model('Direct');
        $flagDeroga = "true" ;

        $this->session->userdata("flagDeroga");
            $data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
            $this->load->model('GaranzieValoreFlexModel');
            //$this->load->view('garanziavalore/garanzie_valore_questionario_bootstrap',$data);
            $this->load->view('garanziavalore/index_tornaIndietro_bootstrap',$data);

    }


    ..................................................... 
    ..................................................... 
    ..................................................... 

}
```

So, from what I have understand, basically this controller handle only the HTTP Request toward the URL: **http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex**.

So from what I have understand the method performed when I access to the previous URL is the **index()** that by this line:

```
$this->load->view('garanziavalore/index_bootstrap',$data);
```

show the **garanziavalore/index_bootstrap.php** page that I found into the **views** directory of my prohect (is it a standard that have to be into the **views** directory?)

Is it my reasoning correct?

If yes I am loading the view passing to id also the **$data** variable that I think is the model containing the data that can be shown in the page, this variable is retrieved by:

```
$data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
```

What exactly does this line?

The last doubt is related the other **back()** method that I have found in the previous controller: is it a method of **CodeIgniter** CI_Controller class or something totally custom defined by the developer that work on this application before me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A controller can handle more than one URL and the class `garanzieValoreFlex` is an example of such a class.

The URL `http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex` will call the `index` method.

The URLs `http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex/back` and `http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex/reset` will call the `back()` and `reset()` methods of the class respectively. These two function are custom additions to the extended class `CI_Controller`.

Codeigniter (CI) URLs follow the pattern `example.com/class/function/argument/`
The function and argument segments are optional.

When a URL uses only a class name such as `example.com/class` then CI will look for and call the `index()` method if it exists. If `index()` does not exist you will get `404 Page Not Found` display.

Your reasoning about `$this->load->view('garanziavalore/index_bootstrap',$data);` is correct. It is standard to put such files in the **views** directory. Optionally, subdirectories of **views** can be used as in `/views/garanziavalore/`.

CI uses a file structure that associates different classes (libraries) with certain paths. Controllers, Models and View classes are stored in their respective folders. Then the `loader` class will know exactly where to start looking for any given "type" of class. For instance, the call to `$this->load->view('garanziavalore/index_bootstrap',$data);` tells the `loader` class to get the file `index_boostrap.php` from the `/application/views/garanzivalore/` directory. The code `$this->load->model('GaranzieValoreFlexModel');` tells the loader to use the file `GaranzieValoreFlexModel.php` in `/application/models/`.

Find documentation of the `loader` class [here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html)

The line of code

```
$data = $this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo");
```

is calling the `userdata` method of the `session` class (library). Think of session data as an array. If the array was defined this way. (This is only pseudo-code for what is accomplished).

```
$userdata = array(); //empty array structure
```

The call `$this->session->userdata("datiPreventivo")` is in effect returning the value of `$userdata["datiPreventivo"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong. I would really recommend you to read the official codeigniter tutorials so that you may understand how the MVC works: 
Below are the links

Codeigniter 2:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/

Codeigniter 3:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

CI controllers handles different urls. If you create a function called index in a controller, it will be loaded automatically when the controller is accessed. For your case, `http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex` should access the function. 
To access any other function, you will need to `http://MYURL/garanzieValoreFlex/**MyFunction**`
(Read more `http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=url#codeigniter-urls`) The back function is a user defined function.